# misunderstanding in matlab

Tags: graph-theory, matlab

guys i have a simple question,which unfortunately i can't understand why it is so?
in matlab for example following code

```
W = [.41 .99 .51 .32 .15 .45 .38 .32 .36 .29 .21];
DG = sparse([6 1 2 2 3 4 4 5 5 6 1],[2 6 3 5 4 1 6 3 4 3 5],W)
```

creats sparse weighted graph like this

```
(4,1)       0.4500
   (6,2)       0.4100
   (2,3)       0.5100
   (5,3)       0.3200
   (6,3)       0.2900
   (3,4)       0.1500
   (5,4)       0.3600
   (1,5)       0.2100
   (2,5)       0.3200
   (1,6)       0.9900
   (4,6)       0.3800
```

and it is a point which i couldn't understand,how it creates edges  i mean we have in this example so many vertex and edge  how,in which order it creates this graph?how it is formed?ones again i am not asking about code ,algorithm or so on,just  i will repeat

from this   `DG = sparse([6 1 2 2 3 4 4 5 5 6 1],[2 6 3 5 4 1 6 3 4 3 5],W)`,how it creates edges which are written above?also how to determine vertex list from this code?which are just vertexes?please help me,if something is not clear from my quetsion i will try to clarify it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take the first elements of your vectors:

> [**6** 1 2 2 3 4 4 5 5 6 1]
>
> [**2** 6 3 5 4 1 6 3 4 3 5]
>
> [**.41** .99 .51 .32 .15 .45 .38 .32 .36 .29 .21]

That gives you the second line of the represented returned matrix (`(6,2)       0.4100` ) and so on.

The visual representation you posted is just ordered differently by Matlab (by matrix columns and lines numbers).